# Grape Vine Plant - Summer Heat

Tags: planting, grape-vine

I live in a place where the temperature would be around 45-48 degrees Celsius during peak summer.

Does grape vine require green-mesh covering on top of the vines as protection, or does plant would be able to tolerate the heat?

Comment: No personal experience with places that hot, but in cooler locations they are often put in greenhouses to get more warmth, so I expect if they have sufficient water they will be fine...

Comment: In Australia the survive fine with rare 44 degrees. I have never seen any covers.